# Pivot a dataframe by splitting a string & format specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am faced with a problem that is above my level of pandas - but might well be simple once I know the steps.

I have a dataframe with column names as below and I want to extract the period from the string of each column and pivot the period to the row as in the second example below.

I also want to format each column differently - currently it is just a number, but some should be % and some numbers and with certain amount of decimals. What I have now and what I want is outlined below.

I have tried a few things - creating a multi index with a string splitting method and then pivoting the multi index. I feel I am on the right track but just cannot make it work at present. Any help appreciated.

what I have now in a dataframe

```
client_return_12m,client_return_36m,client_return_60m,client_sharpe_12m,client_sharpe_36m,client_sharpe_60m
0.34116,0.56439,0.701156,0.74320,0.82349,0.76889
```

after

```
period,client_return,client_sharpe
12m,34.1%,0.74
36m,56.4%,0.82
60m,70.1%,0.77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by last `_` and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis('period').reset_index()
print (df)
  period  client_return  client_sharpe
0    12m       0.341160        0.74320
1    36m       0.564390        0.82349
2    60m       0.701156        0.76889
```